# How to set color on blank cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to set color for the one whole row but the problem is some of my cells are blank cell, not containing any data,

```
        XSSFRow row2 = sheet.getRow(1);

        CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        for (int i = 0; i < row1.getLastCellNum() + 1; i++) {// For each cell in the row
            row2.getCell(i).setCellStyle(style);// Set the style
        }
```

I got error like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I believe this error come from the blank cell because when I try to set color on cell that contain data for example:

```
row2.getCell(4).setCellStyle(style);
```

the particular cell is in color accordingly.

Can we actually put color on a blank cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try below approach.
Here i have given you logic as i don't have exactly the dependency please follow below approach First check if row2.getCell is not null then set otherwise create cell and then set.

```
 XSSFRow row2 = sheet.getRow(1);

            CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
            style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
            style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

            for (int i = 0; i < row2.getLastCellNum(); i++) {// For each cell in the row
                if( row2.getCell(i)!=null){
                row2.getCell(i).setCellStyle(style);// Set the style
                }else{
                    Cell cell=row2.createCell(i);
                    cell.setCellStyle(style);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I got this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column index (16384).  Allowable column range for EXCEL2007 is (0..16383) or ('A'..'XFD')`

Comment: please check now you need to remove +1 from for loop.

Comment: Specifying a [MissingCellPolicy when you get the cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy-) is probably cleaner, and certainly shorter!